# Transformation logic using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transformation

I want to update a column. When the value is not in the list or in table or doesn't match, it will return "Not Account Related" and when the value is in the list, the row will become blank. So this is my query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE Project_Names
       WHEN "List_Value_Name".[LK_ProjectNames] = "Project_Names".[1] 
          THEN ''
          ELSE "Not Account Related"
    END
FROM 
    [master].[dbo].[1]
```

Table is `LK_ProjectNames` with columns `List_Value_Name` & `table 1` with column `Project_Names`.

If value in table 1 column `Project_Names` got in the table `LK_ProjectNames` column `List_Value_Name`, it will return blank. if not it will return `Not Account Related`

Comment: This question is not currently answerable.  Please update to show the table structure of all tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing project name in table1 in one row one project basis.

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LK_ProjectNames l WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(t.Project_Names)) =LTRIM(RTRIM(l.List_Value_Name)) ) THEN '' ELSE 'Not Account Related' END as RESULT
FROM table1 t
```

If you are storing project names as comma seperated  in table1 .

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LK_ProjectNames l WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(t.Project_Names)) like '%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(l.List_Value_Name))+'%' ) THEN '' ELSE 'Not Account Related' END as RESULT
FROM table1 t
```

Comment: how to avoid blank space from affected? because when i run my query, the blank space become 'not account related' too because the value is not matching with the column that i referring.

Comment: In which column you are having blank spaces?  Project_Names or List_Value_Name ? if it comes with both side of the column value use TRIM function .see the updated code.

Comment: Project_Names. Project_Names is the main table that i have to update. I still have to keep the blank space. I just want it to be affected, just ignore the blank space.